# CSS: Image Overflows

Tags: css

I am trying to make images fit inside black border div whether they rotate or not. I have tried overflow:hidden, max-height:100% and object-fit: contain but still images overflow. with transform. I don't know what to try next. Need Help

```
<div style="border: 1px solid">
  <img img-fix-orientation="model.post.image" ng-src="{{model.post.image ? model.post.image : model.post.sub_category.name == 'Service' ? 'images/service.png' : 'images/thing.png'}}" style="max-width:100%;" alt="post image" />
</div>
```

[image: Check element style and image]

Comment: set css  **overflow:hidden** on div

Comment: If you need it to be fit inside, try to put your image as a background image and add the attribute background-size:cover or background-size:contain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Note, `object-fit` lacks good browser support, and there are options to over come that, though here I want to show how `contain` applies with and w/o `transform`.*

To show an image in an `img` element uncut, you use the `object-fit: contain`, set `width` and /or `height` to `100%` and it will make both vertical and horizontal images fit with no overflow.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.wrapper img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/150x300/f00"/>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/00f"/>
</div>
```

---

Now, when you apply `transform: rotate(90deg)` it is only *visually* it does that, so from the document flow perspective, it still is sized/positioned as in the above sample.

This means neither the `wrapper` nor `img` are aware of any changes and therefore one get the overflow when rotate a horizontal `img`, to vertical, in a horizontal `wrapper`.

To be able to rotate such `img` and make it fit vertically, the `transform` needs to know the aspect ratio of the `wrapper` before hand, to be able compensate the overflow, and in this sample it is known (150px / 250px = 0.6), so by adding `scale` to the transform we can avoid an overflow.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
}

.wrapper img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150/00f"/>
</div>
```

---

For a vertical `img` in a vertical `wrapper` one need to apply the same fix.

Comment: display: inline-block on the parent does it for me.

Comment: @eyn -- Given the parent already ___has___ `display: inline-block` set, what do you mean with your comment?

Comment: I simply meant that in my case, I didn't have a display: attribute in the parent and display:inline-block did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

The div must have a set width and height to know what to consider overflow.

If you say the div is 500px wide, then the overflow will apply.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to make this work. You can specify a height for your containing element along with setting the `overflow-y` property to `hidden`. (A height must be set...without one being set, how could the browser know what to consider an overflow?)

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.img {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"/>
</div>

<p>Image element is 150px tall, but the containing element is only 100px tall</p>
```

You could also set the img as a background-image, then use the `background-size: contain` property. **This will preserve the original size of your image**:

```css
.container-sm {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHXH4.png') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}

.container-lg {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHXH4.png') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-lg"></div>
<br/>
<div class="container-sm"></div>

<p>Image is fully contained in div, regardless of image or div size.</p>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes hidden resolve the problem. But is there a way to fit complete image without ruining the aspect ratio and hiding?

Answer (score 1):

give id to your div, let say

```
#divid{
border: 1px solid black;
height: X px;
width: X px;
}

#divid img{

height: 100%;
width: 100%;

}
```

this will fit your image inside div.